# Match on space-separated values in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Properties of items are listed as space-separated terms in a @properties attribute. There is also a master list of properties.

```
<t>

   <items>
     <item id='a' properties='red little' />
     <item id='b' properties='big strong heavy' />
     <item id='c' properties='blue heavy' >
   </items>

   <properties>
     <property id='red' />
     <property id='little' />
     <property id='blue' />
   </properties>

</t>
```

My problem: Using XLST 1.0, write a match attribute for a template that will match all items that have at least one property in the master list of properties.

Items a and c would match. Item b would not.

It's XSLT 1.0, so I can't use str:split. Maybe something with keys and contains()?

Comment: JPM, Please, have a look at my updated answer -- I believe that this is as close as possible to the solution you are after.

Comment: I was indeed looking for a match attribute instead of an in-template conditional (which is what I was using already). Even if that use of current() precludes my using it right now, it was Thomas who first pointed out a solution to the posted qustion. And I marginally prefer his -- it's just a little easier for me to grok. Also, I do think I'd need to surround the needle, and not just the haystack, with spaces, as Thomas and Michael did.

I dare say I should give Thomas the checkmark on this one.

Comment: It's not only a matter of preference here. The solution you prefer is an order of magnitude more complex, error prone and not understandabe and maintenable. Guarding the body of a template with a condition is a good XSLT 1.0 design pattern. People are forced to use this whenever the condition that identifies the nodes to select, contains a variable. In XSLT 2.0 one can put this condition in a predicate in the match pattern. However, in XSLT 1.0 there is a pure syntactic constraint that forbids doing this. In all such cases people simply place this condition in the body to guard the code.

Comment: In other words, guided by the KISS principle, one would always make a good decision by choosing the simplest and shortest solution.

Comment: You mean my preferring Thomas's key over yours, or my preferring the match over the conditional? Given what is going on in the rest of this  particular stylesheet, the match would be more maintainable than a conditional. (That's why I went looking for one.) Or did you mean your key+match is an order of magnitude simpler than Thomas's key+match?

Comment: No, a non-understandable and over-complicated match pattern is never more maintainable than a much simpler, single wrapping condition. My message to you is that in any such case one should prefer the simpler, wrapping condition. I really don't care whether you'd accept my answer or not. What I care about is that any reader should understand that the proven and recommended solution that they need to choose, is the much simpler one.

Comment: I'm not convinced. It depends on context. If I have 25 match patterns, all beautifully orthogonal and in mature, production code. And then someone finds a rare corner condition that requires that I either create a new template with a screwball match or bastardize an existing template with an if or choose condition. Overall maintainability might be better served by isolating the mess in one goofy template.

Comment: JPM, Nobody forces you to use XSLT 1.0. Switch to XSLT 2.0 where this problem is non-existent. And I am not trying to convince *you* -- my comments are for the readers -- hope that my recommendation would help most of them to make the right decision in a case like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the darn browsers force me to use 1.0. Very good point about explaining the best practice and reasons for it. Checkmark goes here for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. One more solution using keys and `current()` :)** :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemByProp" match="item"
  use="boolean(/*/properties/property/@id
                 [contains(concat(' ', current()/@properties, ' '),
                           .)]
              )"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "item[count(.| key('kItemByProp', 'true'))
       =
        count(key('kItemByProp', 'true'))
        ]
  ">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<t>
    <items>
        <item id='a' properties='red little' />
        <item id='b' properties='big strong heavy' />
        <item id='c' properties='blue heavy' />
    </items>
    <properties>
        <property id='red' />
        <property id='little' />
        <property id='blue' />
    </properties>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<item id="a" properties="red little"/>
<item id="c" properties="blue heavy"/>
```

---

**II. Without keys, but having a conditional instruction as the outermost in the template body:**

```
 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:if test=
  "/*/properties/*/@id
        [contains(concat(' ', current()/@properties, ' '), .)]">
    <!-- Your processing here -->
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:if test=
  "/*/properties/*/@id
        [contains(concat(' ', current()/@properties, ' '), .)]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<item id="a" properties="red little"/>
<item id="c" properties="blue heavy"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `<xsl:if>` as well?

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="/t/properties/property[contains(concat(' ', current()/@properties, ' '), concat(' ', @id, ' '))]">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, `current()` cannot be used within the `match` attribute.

Comment: I am trying not to insert something inside the plain `match="item"`. I'm hoping for a separate template that takes priority when the condition I described matches. If I can.

Comment: Could you use `<xsl:choose>` instead of `<xsl:if>` to handle the cases when the condition matches versus when it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Using Michael Liu's XPath expression, you can also construct a key that lets you match the correct elements:

```
<xsl:key name="inMaster" match="item" use="
    substring(
      '1',
      1,
      string-length(
        /t/properties/property[
          contains(concat(' ', current()/@properties, ' '), concat(' ', @id, ' '))
        ]/@id
      )
    )"/>

<!-- The following template matches the wanted item elements -->
<xsl:template match="key('inMaster','1')">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

We use the `substring()` function to associate matching `<item>` elements with the string `"1"`. All item elements that don't match are associated with the empty string as there is no matching "master" property, and therefore no `id` attribute, therefore the `string-length()` is 0, therefore we extract a substring of length 0 (i.e. an empty string).

Comment: Hmm. That's an idea. Unfortunately, this app is running in a browser and I have found that current() doesn't work inside @use in Chrome or Safari.